# Window Overlay dispatch back button event to foreground Activity of other app from service

Tags: android, android-service, back-button, accessibility

I have a service which creates a window overlay on some other app. I am handling back button press in the service through dispatchKeyEvent on the layout. How can I pass this event(back press) to the foreground app(other app, not mine) also ?